# Как фиксить mbr Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, пароль

Есть Windows 7, домаш. версия. Забыли пароль, и хотел перезаписать через ERD commender.Проблема в том что ЭРД не видит ОС -а, пишет "Operating System not found". Захожу через установочный диск выбираю. [Делаю вот как здесь.](http://www.oszone.net/11294/)  "Восстановление системы" -- Через ком. строку --, пишу

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbrbootrec.exe /fixbootbootrec.exe /rebuildbcdbootrec.exe /scanos
```

выводит, что ни одна ОС не обнаружена. Просто 0. Но у меня же загружается Винда, и запрашивает пароль учетки. Как тогда не видит? Помогите, ребята.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mbr не имеет никакого отношения к паролю учетной записи win (как я понял, именно этот пароль забыли). Посмотреть, как восстановить пароль можно тут:[три способа сбросить пароль в Windows 7: простой, сложный и неправильный](http://www.3dnews.ru/workshop/623507).

Answer (score 0):

> Проблема в том что ЭРД не видит ОС -а, пишет "Operating System not found"

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. И теперь непонятно, зачем надо было фиксить mbr, если винда загружается.

Comment: а почему тогда Винда загружается ?

Comment: А что ей не загружаться, если все впорядке, вопрос в другом, какая версия ERD'ды используется? Какой HDD (IDE или SATA) и на конец на каком разделе стоит винда? ERD'е, может, что то не нравится из перечисленного.